# Linked SQL Server - Pass a use command or define default database

Tags: sql-server

I have a set of SQL queries  that need to be run against 3 databases, they are stored on 2 different servers that have been linked.
All 3 databases have the the exact same tables and tables name, however the database names are different.
The queries have been written and all use just table names not the full database.dbo.table syntax so I can't use an automated find and replace on "linked.database1" to "linked.database2"
All the queries will always be executed through one server "Server1"

I'm trying to come up with a method of passing the queries to one of the linked servers but have a "use" command go through as it means I only have to change the database in the "use" line.

So far I have tried the following from Server1:

```
Select * from [Linked].Database.DBO.Table - Successful
Exec ('Select * from [Linked].Database.DBO.Table') - Successful
```

Direct on Server2 (using the account the linked server operates on):

```
EXEC ('Use Database; SELECT * from Table') - Successful
```

So with these above three I can ascertain

1. The login on Server1 can reach the databases needed and can access the data with a basic select and when passed with and Exec command.
2. The account on Server2 can run the Exec command and passing the "Use Database" line with Exec works on Server2.

However when I try using the below:

```
Select * from openquery ([Linked], 'Exec (Use Database; Select * from Table)')
```

I get the following error:

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "172.20.11.123" returned message "Deferred prepare could not be completed.".
Msg 8180, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Statement(s) could not be prepared.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Use'.
```

Have I messed up the syntax anywhere in the OpenQuery or can the USE command never be passed through OpenQuery.
If what I'm trying to do with OpenQuery and USE isn't possible then is there a way of passing the database you want the OpenQuery run against in the statement?

Or as a second thought, is there a way of putting together the Linked Server account so that it uses a particular database as its default database?

Comment: I've trialed setting the default database on the login account on the linked server and that worked. However I would like to avoid having to use this method as it means I will have to have multiple connection strings and SQL accounts for passing the SQL commands through and I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: The openquery version has far fewer `'` characters. Have you tried something like `'Exec (''Use Database; Select * from Table'')'` instead?

Comment: I don't quite follow your constraints but if you have to stick with [linkedserver]...[Table] syntax (not mentioning the database name), then for consistency I suggest you create a linked server per _database_. So you''ll have two linked servers against the same server, but with different defailt databases.

Comment: How do you know which ‘Use database’ to pass? Are the queries for each target database always executed from the same source database? Or are there different users only executing against a specific target database? I just wonder if there’s a possibility to have database-specific synonyms or views that are hard-coded to a specific target table or even synonyms or views with the same base name under different schemas, and the separate users could have different default schemes so they would automatically pick up the right synonym or view. Still trying to map the abstract to your real scenario.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have access to both servers. I know the linked server names and database names. The Databases have all been set-up by the same third program so contain exactly the same structure. They are the datastore for this program from when our 3 offices weren't networked together. However when they were set-up they were given different names (before I started). Because of unique numbers already issued to clients and used for other things (marking files for customers) we cannot merge the 3 databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the way to do this, as far as I can tell, if you know which database you need to execute against:

```
DECLARE @database sysname = N'Database1';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.Table;';

DECLARE @exec nvarchar(4000) = N'[Linked].' 
   + QUOTENAME(@database) + N'.sys.sp_executesql';

EXEC @exec @sql;
```

I'm not quite sure what this was trying to accomplish:

```
Select * from openquery ([Linked], 
  'Exec (Use Database; Select * from Table)')
```

But if you take out from that what you're trying to tell `[Linked]` to `EXEC`, it's this:

```
Exec (Use Database; Select * from Table)
```

Try that anywhere. Broken. You might get it to work like this, as @AlwaysLearning suggested:

```
Select * from openquery ([Linked], 
  'Exec (''Use Database; Select * from Table'')')
```

...but that's kind of, like, really gross, compared to the solution at the top. Unless you absolutely need to select from openquery for some reason.